# How can I use a custom editor template when using data annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple model:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public MyCustomType EmailAddress {get; set; }
}
```

In a certain view, I need to present an input box to allow editing of this property.  Ideally I want to keep using the standard `@Html.EditorFor` syntax, so I've created a `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyCustomType.cshtml` template:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyCustomType
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeStringProperty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I also have a custom `IModelBinder` to read this input back into `MyCustomType` when it's submitted, this all works fine.

However, as you can see from the property name, this property contains an Email address. I'd like to use the standard data annotations attributes to mark it as such, and then update `MyCustomType.cshtml` to make use of it to render an `<input type="email">` input box when necessary - not all uses of `MyCustomType` are email addresses, hence wanting to use the standard attributes to mark it as such.  When I do so:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    [EmailAddress]
    public MyCustomType EmailAddress {get; set; }
}
```

My custom template is no longer used - it instead reverts back to using the standard `EditorFor` code, and essentially just displays the `.ToString()` version of `MyCustomType` inside an `<input>`, rather than my custom editor template which pulls out a specific property.

Is there a way to make it use my custom editor template functionality, while still only requiring models to add the standard data annotations attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data annotations always take precedence over the type when it comes to editor templates. You have a few options:

1. Create a custom "EmailAddress" attribute. Technically, I think you could pretty much just subclass `EmailAddressAttribute` without actually adding anything additional. The name of your custom attribute, though, would allow you to have a different editor template for that.
2. Go ahead and use the `EmailAddress.cshtml` editor template, but branch inside. Assuming `MyCustomType` inherits from `String`:

   ```
   @model String
   @if (Model is MyCustomType)
   {
       ...
   }
   else
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Probably the easiest method, though, is to simply specify the template. It's not quite as automatic, but it doesn't require any additional work:

   ```
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "MyCustomType")
   ```

   Which would then load `MyCustomType.cshtml` instead of the default `EmailAddress.cshtml`.

Comment: So what's happening at the moment is that it's just overriding it with a different "custom" editor template?  That makes sense.  I'll probably play with option 2 for a bit - I'd really like to make using this as smooth as possible without having to do anything "special" in the views etc.  Back soon after experimenting...

Comment: I went with option 2, seems to be working nicely, thanks!

Comment: Ugh, except the attribute is internally effectively using `.ToString` on the submit to see if it's valid or not, thus breaking it (I can't have `.ToString` return the underlying string - it breaks the point of what I'm trying to achieve) - looks like I might need to switch to either option 1 or a combination thereof... Either way - your answer helped point out what was going on.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a question about the actual problem you're trying to solve. It's highly atypical to subclass something like `String`, so it feels like there's probably a better way. You might have an XY problem here, where you're too focused on fixing your chosen solution that you're missing a better solution that would be less problematic.

Comment: I haven't subclassed `String` - it's a class that contains a string property that is the sole representation of the data.  Essentially I was playing with having a class that we use to hold _any_ user input rather than normal strings - any time you then want to use it anywhere you have to use the relevant method to get it encoded for where you're using it - there's been numerous occasions in the past where things aren't encoded at all, this would at least force people to think about it a bit.  Having `.ToString` return the underlying string is "wrong", as it removes having to think about it.

Comment: This email attribute is only a small part of it - I'm still weighing up whether or not the whole thing is worth it - hence why I'm trying to make things like `@Html.EditorFor` work "as expected", without creators of the views needing to think about things at that level